# Short/Long press in a item of ListView

Tags: android, listview, long-press

I have a ListView with some items and I want to have different responses when I make an `itemClick` (short press) and an `itemLongClick` (long press):

```
       list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               //play file
           }
       });

       list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               //Message 
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "FILE: "+itemsFiles.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               return false;
           }       
       });
```

When I make a short press (`onItemClick()`) my app works well and it plays the file.
My problem is when I make a long press (`onItemLongClick()`) because it appears the message with Toast but it plays the file too, and I do not want to play the file in this case ... How I can solve it and correctly distinguish the two cases?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: -1 for not reading the documentation: please check the documentation of `AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener`, what it should returns and why?

Comment: Try to return 'true' in onItemLongClick method.

Comment: @Selvin I'm so sorry for this silly question. I assure you that I read the documentation but I did not understand what the method returned: 

**true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise** 

Due to your blunt response reread it carefully and realized the error.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to have  look upon this tutorial : http://android.konreu.com/developer-how-to/click-long-press-event-listeners-list-activity/